# Colored emojis memory usage

Tags: android, ios, memory, android-bitmap

it's known that bitmaps consume 4 bytes of memory per pixel,

so does emojis in text consume the same amount of memory in Android and IOS devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests on an Android device

I created an empty activity 
measured the used memory: ~3MB

added 2000 Emojis (default system emojis,dpi 160, Text Size: 30)
now the memory: 14MB

I did the same test again with Text size: 50
the memory: 19MB

which means that Emojis somehow consume the same amount of memory as bitmaps.

Answer (score -1):

On Android and probably on iOS all emojis in text are handled as unicode character points.

See http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html for a list for emojis.

Mostly likely that apps will be using UTF-8 encoding of the characters so will use between 1 and 4 bytes per character (though most likely emojis will be 3 or 4 bytes with a small few being 2 bytes)

Comment: Note that the shapes of the emojis are also stored somewhere in memory, just in a more efficient format than bitmaps.

Comment: Yes, the emojis have a storage cost on disk type memory when not being used and also in graphics memory when being drawn, but this is not their cost of memory when being stored "in text". The question is vague but taking the purest view that text is made of characters, I gave just the character size cost.